# Postfix local delivery rewriting address so that it is not deliverable

Tags: ubuntu, postfix, email-server

I have a basic Ubuntu Server 9.04 install with Postfix freshly installed via `apt-get`.  When I do a

```
sendmail -bv vlewis@bunner.ath.cx
```

where `vlewis` is a unix account.

The delivery report I get says that it failed to deliver because the address -f-@bunner.ath.cx is a bad recipient address.

```
    This is the mail system at host moose.bunner.ath.cx.

    Enclosed is the mail delivery report that you requested.

                       The mail system

    : delivery via local: delivers to command:
        /usr/bin/procmail

    : delivery via local: bad recipient address syntax:
        -f-@bunner.ath.cx
```

Why is it rewriting the username.  Please help.  This is driving me nuts!

(I'm adding this string to make this problem less Google resistant because you cannot Google for -f- so I add dash f dash in an attempt to help).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does that user have a .forward file setup?

Comment: That fixed it.  The user had a .forward that piped through procmail (the home directory was copied from an old system) and Postfix was already using procmail.

Comment: Great, I'm glad :-) (Feel free to vote me up) ;-)